# My MacBook Pro 2018 refuses to turn on

Tags: macbook-pro

So I slept off with the MBP plugged to power. When I woke up and tried to switch it on it wouldn’t come on. I’ve tried clicking the touchpad and it’s responsive.

Holding the power button down doesn’t help, rather the Touch Bar shows a red light for a split second.

I’ve also tried the shift+control+option+power button with no success

Comment: If it doesn’t turn on, you need to take it in for service as there’s nothing you can do at this point.

Comment: Are you able to boot into [Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) by holding Command (⌘)-R on reboot? Try to repair your system volume using Disk Utility. Also have a look at this [support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204267)

Comment: HackAfro, I am facing the exact same problem. Any tips on how to resolve?

Comment: @ArunaHerah It turned out to be water damage, had to replace the screen